# Casimir Effect & Redshifting

Tags: dark-energy, redshift, casimir-effect

The classic plate experiment highlights how omitted wavelengths of light create an energy differential and pressure. This pressure is dependent on the distance between the plates, including how this distance determines the omitted wavelengths of light.

Could the equation be generalized for any case where wavelengths differ and an energy differential exists? E.g., redshifted cosmological objects being acted on by light sources from our local frame of reference?